# The plugins failed to load properly

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, virtualbox

I am trying to run my vagrant, but it keeps giving me errors. I've tried to delete and reinstall plugins using vagrant commands, but still no success. Here's the error:

````
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.

cannot load such file -- vagrant/command```
````

Comment: Would it be possible to tell more about it? 
What are you trying to do first? Any screenshots are welcome.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. On the contrary of what was asked by @user10550971, please **do not provide screenshots unless it is absolutely necessary**. In your case, copy/pasting in code blocks (as you did) is the way to go. Meanwhile, you still need to provide more info, at the very list the exact commands you used and probably your Vagrantfile. Does this happens on only one project or on all projects you have ? What happens if you test in a brand new blank project ? If it breaks everywhere, you may have to reinstall Vagrant correctly. Else, you may just have to fix your particular project.

Comment: Thank you so much @Zeitounator . I have some other errors too, but they are fixable and less time consuming.